How can I change the width of an element with 'display: inline;'?
I wanted to create my first little website with HTML and CSS. The website should include 10 boxes which are located next to each other and have a width of 100px. I managed to locate them in a row, but they do not have the correct width.
How it looks like
This is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 1500px;
        }
        #container div {
            width: 100px;
            display: inline;
            background-color: gray;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div>Box 1</div>
        <div>Box 2</div>
        <div>Box 3</div>
        <div>Box 4</div>
        <div>Box 5</div>
        <div>Box 6</div>
        <div>Box 7</div>
        <div>Box 8</div>
        <div>Box 9</div>
        <div>Box 10</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

I tried to change the width of the divs, but nothing happend.

U need inline block

The 'display: inline;' property prevents 'width:' from having an effect. You should use 'display: inline-block;' instead.
